# Are the original vampires in The Vampire Diaries/The Originals really indestructible?

Tags: the-vampire-diaries, the-originals

In *The Vampire Diaries* universe, the original vampire family does not have any of the usual vampire vulnerabilities. They can only be killed with special weapons.

But what if you were to destroy their body completely? For example, decapitate them? Or rip our their heart? Or dismember and dissect their bodies into small pieces and scatter them around?

Would they still heal?

Comment: FYI: I sent a tweet to *The Originals* writers in hopes they might wander over with an official response; can we not close the question just yet?

Comment: decapitating is not the same as completely destroying body though. As per ripping their heart - yeah, that wouldn't work, Elijah did rip Marcel's heart out while he had that super-original serum in his system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this point, there is no canon answer for this question. As far as I know, none of the Michaelsons have ever been seriously injured in the manner you're describing. As these shows are not really known for their strict and consistent canon, until it happens on-screen it would be difficult to even speculate.

However, if we take the show at face value then we have to assume yes, they would eventually heal from this. The primary reason is, none of the people who are actively trying to kill them have *tried* to do this to them yet.

In particular, we know of at least one person who has both the skill and the desire to try this with one of the Michaelsons -- their father Michael. He spent his entire life hunting them down, but more importantly, hunting down the white oak stake that would allow him to kill his children. He wants to get rid of all vampires, and killing one of the original line would wipe out huge chunks at a time.

We know that, even though they will heal from serious injury, there are ways to *temporarily* subdue an original. Their cursed daggers, for example, will put them into a permanent state of suspended animation, and we've seen other magic items take them down as well. We have to assume, if all he had to do was subdue one and then decapitate or cut them up, he would have done so (or at least made an effort to do so) instead of focusing all his effort on acquiring one of the magic weapons.

Comment: Makes me wonder:  If you used a cursed dagger on an original then dismembered them the piece is no longer connected so would it come back to life?  I think it would make some interesting stories if it did :)

Comment: I have a strong impression that "the heart" is a key part of the vampire curse (they always talk about the dagger going into the heart). my *assumption* is that the piece that would regenerate itself from scratch is that, so you ripped out their heart and daggered it, the rest would dust. I'm guessing we're never going to see that, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I too have been wondering such things, though I always inevitably come back to the fact that this is merely a TV show that isn't required to put forth any degree of logic to us viewers.

My belief is this: clearly you can only kill an Original with the white oak, but their bodies as a whole are not indestructible and they don't magically regrow limbs and organs. If you were to remove an Original vampire's extremities, head, and heart, and then placed these body parts on 6 different continents...they may not be "eternally" dead, but effectively they would be dead. Just picture Klaus' arms in Asia, his head in South America, his heart in Australia, etc...unless his body parts can fly individually than the chances that he gets "reassembled" are essentially 0%. So Originals are actually quite easy to incapacitate, but the chances of this scenario arising in the show also stands at 0%.

Comment: My distinct suspicion is that he'd regenerate from the heart.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the wiki it says that their body is indestructible. That only the special enchanted weapons or the White Oak Stake can kill them. There is some thermos that magic strong enough could kill them for the magic could kill them from the inside out. The wiki says that their heart is impossible to get pulled out by hand and that thier limbs cannot be pulled off. So I would say yes they are indestructible to anything besides any very powerful magical object.

Answer (score -1):

Such as happened with Rayna Cruz, I think their bodies would burn, and then magically a new body would rise from the ashes.